# Read, preprocess, and save images to specified location in opencv

Tags: python

Sorry if the question's been asked before, I couldn't find a solution that I either implemented correctly or that helped achieve my desired results.

Summary: The script should look inside a folder, import images using opencv, apply a filter to the images, and finally save the pre-processed image to the specified path. The names should ideally contain the original filename plus "preproc" added, or anything indicating having been filtered.

What works: I managed to read all images, import them, and apply the filter.

---

[Save images in loop with different names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535290/save-images-in-loop-with-different-names)

This helped some.

---

[Save multiple images with OpenCV and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119544/save-multiple-images-with-opencv-and-python)

This worked before but I don't think I had implemented it into the script that read all images.

---

```
from __future__ import (division, absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals)
import glob
import os,sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


########
#Globals
#########

img_dir = "path_to_images/*.*"

###########
#Functions
###########

def white_balance(img):
result = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
avg_a = np.average(result[:, :, 1])
avg_b = np.average(result[:, :, 2])
result[:, :, 1] = result[:, :, 1] - ((avg_a - 128) * (result[:, :, 0] / 255.0) * 1.1)
result[:, :, 2] = result[:, :, 2] - ((avg_b - 128) * (result[:, :, 0] / 255.0) * 1.1)
result = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
return result


## Get all the images in the specified dir:
images = sorted(glob.glob(img_dir))




#Reading images in folder
for image in images:
    img = cv.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, image)) #Read images one by one

    ################
    #Pre-processing#
    ################
    #Performing white balancing (gray world)
    #final = np.hstack((img, white_balance(img))) #white balancing; showing Original and filtered.
    final = white_balance(img) #white balance on a single image.


    #Saving images:
    i = 0
    cv.imwrite("path_to_results/preproc%04i.jpg" %i, final) #save images in sequence (numbering)
    i += 1 #numbering variable
```

---

What doesn't work: Images are saved but somewhere I haven't specified correctly an index to save the images in a sequence (i.e. result_1, result_2,...). The script overwrites the last image only.

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is reinitialized in the loop every time to 0. Try the same code by declaring i = 0 outside the for loop.

Comment: That was it. Thanks :)